# downloading a text file from a website

Tags: java, android

i have done up a method to return a string values of a textfile which is hosted on a site

but i cant seem to get the value out when i call the method

```
private String DownloadFromUrl() //this is the downloader method
{  
    String strFileContents = null;
    try 
    {
            String webURL = "http://www.example.net/test/file.txt";
            URL url = new URL(webURL);

            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            /*
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            //create a byte array
            byte[] contents = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead=0;

            while( (bytesRead = bis.read(contents)) != -1){

                strFileContents += new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
            }

       }

    catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }
    return strFileContents;        
}
```

i got a null pointer exception thrown from the stringreader

```
 //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    String test = DownloadFromUrl();

    try {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(test);
        String line="";
        int c,counter =0;
        while ((c = sr.read()) != -1) 
        {
            line+=(char)c;
            counter++;
        }

        char[] singleText = line.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            classifier(singleText[i]);
        }
        text.append(line);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }
```

i tested my code and the error was thrown form the stringreader with a null pointer

but works correctly when i test with a string text.

so the problem would lie on the DownloadFromUrl method not returning the string of text from the online .txt file

added the error message hope this helps

[image]
[image]

Comment: log the exception and put it over here which exception it throws

Comment: i am sorry i am not sure on how to log and view the exception been viewing logcat and the console but i know that i am thrown an nullpointer exception

Comment: Don't catch the exception at all and let the method throw the exception. Then *handle* it on a higher level. (Or at least like @Jigar says log it)

Comment: just add `ex.printstacktrace()` and re run and check the console

Comment: updated with more reference code hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This to convert InputStream to String

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
return sb.toString();
```

}
}

Comment: thanks for this method i manage to grep the text from the file already

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some logging in order to figure out what is wrong.  For both of your `catch` blocks, do the following:

```
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That will help you narrow down where the issue is.  I would also follow the suggestion of @Jignesh Dhua on converting your `InputStream` into a `String`.

**EDIT**
From your screenshot it looks like `test` is `null` so your when you try and create a `StringReader` it fails with a `NullpointerException`.  To prevent your application from crashing, you can check for `null` before creating your `StringReader`.

This will avoid a crash, but doesn't get you your data.  I would check the [response code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) from the server before reading the content:

```
int responseCode = urlc.getResponseCode();
```

I've also explicitly used `HttpUrlConnection` in the past, though I'm not sure how much difference it would make:

```
/* Open a connection to that URL. */
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: @dave.c hmm i added the print stack, but where do i access the log if any? logcat shows a lot of stuff basically everything that is moving on the phone will try out the inputstream into string method just had dinner

Comment: @benjamin lee logcat is the place to look.  The exception should appear in yellow or red if you are using either the ddms view in Eclipse or the standalone ddms tool.

Comment: @dave.c yep i had posted the exception already as screenshot on my question

Comment: yep i know that the problem is with the part on reading the text file just that i am trying to solve it will try ur method. btw how do i use the getResponseCode? i mean what value will it return if the connection fails and such

Comment: @dave.c thank you for your help i manage to do the grepping already. do you mind helping me with handling the exceptions? can point me to somewhere with some good explanation on how to catch the exception? like when i retrieve the file if the file is blank the application can pop up a alert dialog with buttons to retry and such thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @benjamin lee an exception handling strategy is a whole topic unto itself.  I'f I were you I'd do some research first, then if you still have doubts raise a new question on the site.

Comment: yep thats what i meant.. i was asking other than google developers where else can i read up on exception handling. was asking if you have any good read to recommend